# How to access Canvas.Left property of a StackPanel in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

suppose I have the following XAML:

```
<Canvas Grid.Column="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >

    <StackPanel Name="myStackPanel" Canvas.Left="80">

    </StackPanel>
</Canvas>
```

How can I access/modify the Canvas.Left property of the StackPanel in code?

Simply writing

```
myStackPanel.Left // not a property of StackPanel
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured it:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(myStackPanel, newValue);
```

Comment: that is the case for all attached dependency properties... you will find two static methods GetMyProperty & SetMyProperty on the type registering it. (that's a convention)

Comment: Don't manipulate UI elements' properties in procedural code in WPF. Use DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore: There is nothing wrong with a view modifying itself in the code behind.  A View Model should not be that tightly coupled to the design of any given view.  If he's implementing a window manager, then sure, bind `Canvas.Left` to `WindowModel.Left`; a window's position is a core property that the View Model should be aware of.  If he's tweaking some element that the View Model has no reason to know about, then he's fine doing it procedurally.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I know that, but most probably it's the first case.

Comment: Hey guys, if someone clicks a button I want to make an image disappear. When that image disappears, the things to the right of it need to move left. Is that ok?

Comment: Well, you probably shouldn't be using a `Canvas` to lay out any kind of form or standard UI.  There are better layout panels to choose from, and you can lay things out such that toggling the visibility of the image will automatically cause the other controls to reposition themselves accordingly.  There are very few cases where you should be using absolute positioning; it's a real pain, especially if your window is resizable.

Comment: You've actually just described a problem that I'm trying to work around. The reason I'm using Canvas is that I need to overlay an small image on top of another larger image in a very specific location. The problem is when I resize the window the larger image isn't maintaining its alignment with the window as I need it to.

Comment: As @MikeStrobel said, using other container controls such as a `Grid` will save you endless time... you can still overlay two objects within the same `Grid` cell. The difference is that when the `Window` is resized, so is the `Grid`... and all automatically. Everything will keep its relative position. However, can I suggest that you ask a new question for your new problem as these comments are getting long now.

Comment: Thanks Sheridan for the point of advice. I'll give that a try, and if I get nowhere with it I'll post a new question.